# IDEAL GASSES TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' 3.4.4?

Tags: python, list, graph, physics

I want to make a program to graph two ideal gasses but the shell launch this error:

```
line 10, in P1
    return (P*(Vn[c]))/(T[c2])
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

This is my program:

```
  #Prueba de gráfica de gas ideal con volumen molar
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt    
#Sea Vn=miu/densidad... VnNeón=16.82 ml/mol, VnCriptón=32.23 ml/mol
Vn=[16.82,32.23]
T=[0.01,60,137,258]
c=0 #contador del material
c2=0 #contador temperatura
def P1(P): #Función de P:
    return (P*(Vn[c]))/(T[c2])
P= list(range(0,800))
while c<=1:
    while c2<=3:
        print(P1(P),Vn[c],T[c2])
        c2=c2+1    
    c=c+1
```

What could I do?
I'm using Python 3.4.4 in windows 10. I want obtain a graph of P1 that depends of P(and P goes from 0 to 800), for each temperature in the list T for each Molar Volume of Neon and Kripton in the list Vn.
Why I can't multiply and divide those elements of the list by P?
Thank you so much.

Comment: You were supposed to enter your code where it said "enter code here".

Comment: Sorry, i already posted the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little debugging helps a long way. Changing your function to

```
def P1(P): #Función de P:
    print(type(P), type(Vn[c]), type(T[c2]))
    return (P*(Vn[c]))/(T[c2])
```

And running it prints

> <class> 'list' <class 'float'> <class 'float'>

You're trying to multiple a `list` with two `floats`, which obviously does not work. `P = list(range(0, 800))`, so you will need to use some indexing. I'm not sure what you want to do, but, as an example, the following functions runs fine for me:

```
def P1(P): #Función de P:
    #         | just added an index here
    return (P[0]*(Vn[c]))/(T[c2])
```